# Probability of a randomly generated string being already present in a data set

Tags: probability, randomness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple combination/probability question based on string-length and possible-characters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25211/simple-combination-probability-question-based-on-string-length-and-possible-char)

Suppose I have a collection of 1,000,000 unique strings where each string is exactly 10 characters long, the characters being A-Z, a-z, 0-9. What is the probability of having a string colliding with existing data -- and -- how do I calculate this probability.

Comment: @cardinal yes, and the dupe has a very nice answer

Comment: @David: The wording of my comment is automatically generated when someone votes to close a question as an *exact duplicate*. It is nice that it draws attention explicitly to the proposed duplicate. Matt's answer there turned out very nice which is one reason I wanted to call attention to it (+1 to your comment).

Comment: While this is definitely a very similar question to the suggested duplicate, it's not exactly the same. Given the level of the question, I don't think it's reasonable to assume that the questioner could infer the answer to this question from the (excellent) answer to the other.

Comment: I did go through the other question but I wasn't able to deduce the answer to my question from Matt's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 62 distinct characters available, so the total number of possibilities available is $62^{10} \simeq 8.4 \times 10^{17}$. Assuming that you're sampling uniformly from this set, and you have $10^6$ unique values already, the probability of a collision is $\frac{10^6}{62^{10}} \simeq 1.2 \times 10^{-12}$, or about one in a trillion.

Answer (score 0):

I initially failed to read your assumption that the 1000000 strings you start with are unique. Here is my solution to the corresponding problem where you have 1000000 strings and ask the probability that at least two of them are the same:

This is like a generalization of [The Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). This is the classical problem asks, if there are $n$ people in a room, what is the probability that at least two of them share a birthday. In this problem, the number of people is $n = 1,000,000$ and the number of possible birthdays is $d = (26+26+10)^{10} = (62)^{10}$. The wikipedia gives an asymptotic result of

$$p \simeq 1 - \exp(-n(n-1)/(2d)) = 5.96\times10^{-7}$$.

Comment: This depends intimately on the actual question of interest. For a short discussion of these competing interpretations, you might also look at the duplicate question given in the comments. In this case, note that the OP has explicitly stated that initial strings are unique.

Comment: Ah, correct. I missed that.

Comment: I think the problem should be put this way: (i) if calendar has 62^10 days in an year (ii) there are 1,000,000 people in a room, what is the probability that a person entering the room has same birthday as that of one of the people in the room.